# How to access a Media Recorder object across different html page?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to access a MediaRecorder object across different html pages. This is because I want the recorder to start/stop recording depending on which html page is loaded/which button is clicked. 
Currently, I tried using sessionStorage to store the MediaRecorder object but it seems like sessionStorage only takes in String value? Is there a way to make the MediaRecorder a global variable so different html pages and their javascript files can access it?

Comment: You should instead use postMessage.

Comment: postMessage is used for String types right? I have never use this before but I'm not sure how I would be able to trigger the start and stop functions of the mediaRecorder object through postMessage

Comment: You'll have to come up with a protocol of sorts for doing so.  What I normally do is serialize JSON messages.  You might use something like `{ event: 'stopRecording' }`.  Then, serialize as JSON and send it from your controller page to your recording page.

Comment: I apologize if this is a trivial question. My follow up question would be if I setup the MediaRecorder object in a script loaded from a html page A and then I change to another html page B. Wouldn't the MediaRecorder object no longer exist?

Comment: That's correct.  Sorry, I thought you meant you had different windows/tabs open.  Yeah, there's no way to keep that MediaRecorder alive without keeping the whole context running.